# LinkedIn starter kit not sharing content to wall If add content dictionary?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, linkedin-api

I have written code to post content to linkedIn wall and it is working fine if I remove content dictionary from update dictionary. See the below code containing post data:

```
- (IBAction)postUpdate
    {
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
     OAMutableURLRequest *request =
     [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                     consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                        token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                     callback:nil
                            signatureProvider:nil];

     NSDictionary *content=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"http://www.celebs101.com/wallpapers/Bruce_Lee/421101/Bruce_Lee_Wallpaper.jpg",@"submitted-image-url",@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GoZ2Be2zLq8",@"submitted-url",@"Post Image and Video testing",@"title",@"Posted Description",@"description",nil];

     NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [[NSDictionary alloc]
                              initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",
                             @"Test posting to linkedIn", @"comment",content,@"content",nil];


     [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
     NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];

     [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
     [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                          delegate:self
                 didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
                   didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];
    }
```

Post data comes in didfinishSelector is :

data after posting is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <error>
      <status>401</status>
      <timestamp>1356601471318</timestamp>
      <request-id>MFW58DCKE9</request-id>
      <error-code>0</error-code>
      <message>[unauthorized]. OAU:0onill9cburx|3c05c306-aad8-4d07-a2a1-2430aa21b54a|*01|*01:1356601465:Ji7pimMqrXp3RHCNJLv8iKZsklk=</message>
    </error>
```

I don't know why so? please help.. 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: and is there any error being reported back in the "`postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:`" method?

Comment: postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish: calls

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, however the api documentation says here: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/api-requests-json that you should set the x-li-format header to json if you want to use json format

Comment: there is or options   x-li-format: json
or
Content-type: application/json

Comment: Where is the or option? I can read this: You will need to set Content-Type to application/json on your JSON posts as well as setting the "x-li-format" header to "json". I'm not native English speaking but "as well as" should mean "and" not "or". Am I wrong?

Comment: @MichelePercich see the code below I have answered yet , it is working code that I have solved and it is working without x-li-format" header to "json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it

working code to post on LinkedIn as follows:

```
- (IBAction)postUpdate
{
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
 OAMutableURLRequest *request =
 [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                 consumer:oAuthLoginView.consumer
                                    token:oAuthLoginView.accessToken
                                 callback:nil
                        signatureProvider:nil];

 NSMutableDictionary *contentDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

 [contentDic setValue:@"http://www.celebs101.com/wallpapers/Bruce_Lee/421101/Bruce_Lee_Wallpaper.jpg" forKey:@"submitted-image-url"];
 [contentDic setValue:@"http://www.linkedin.com" forKey:@"submitted-url"];
 [contentDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"A title for your share"] forKey:@"title"];


 NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [[NSDictionary alloc]
                          initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",
                         @"Test posting to linkedIn",@"comment",contentDic,@"content",nil];

 [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];


 NSLog(@"json string is %@",updateString);

 [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

 [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                      delegate:self
             didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
               didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];
}


- (void)postUpdateApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinish:(NSData *)data
{
 NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"data after posting is %@",myString);
}


- (void)postUpdateApiCallResult:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFail:(NSData *)error
{
 NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

Comment: sorry, currently I don't have any dummy code.At that time I had when I posted this.And will it'll take some time to create new one.

Comment: i got this error 'OAuthStarterKit[577:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' please help me.

Comment: they is some empty array in which anycode is messing with.Just read the flow and check out.

Comment: this time not possible bro ,very busy in these days sorry.

Comment: if possible help me sir, i expecting much more from you i have to replay my boss, so reply me if possible otherwise its fine. thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35588/discussion-between-hayassusa-and-bhavesh-nai)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that type of error:

[image]

So it may be because of post url in "submitted-url" key.
So an easy way to do this first make the post_url for "submitted-url" short using this link(   http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=post_url). And then use this short post_url for "submitted-url" value. This can be a solution of your problem.

Sometimes long url for "submitted-url" key cause a that kind of problem.